How search and locate (row and column of) substring in entire df?
I have a large df with 70+ columns and 1 milions+ rows, I would like to find and locate the a substring
I tried
df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('substring').any(), axis=1)
I now only know which rows contains the substring, not which columns

If that works, do another apply with the parameter axis=0? axis=1 is row-wise, axis=0 is column-wise.

Thanks, this worked!

You can use df.isin() to get a series of bool that tell you where the string is present. Then, I like to stack it and use boolean indexing. This might help:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

x = np.array([[0., 1., 1., 'string', 0., 0.],
              [0., 1., 1., 'substring', 0., 0.],
              [0., 1., 1., 'substring', 0., 0.],
              [0., 1., 1., 'string', 0., 0.]])
print(x)
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=y)
print('Original df: ')
print(df)
result = df.isin(['substring'])
print('result: ', result)
pos = result.stack()
print('pos: ', pos)
string_pos = pos[pos].index.to_list()  # boolean indexing: Gets indexes where the val is True.
print('string_pos: ', string_pos)


Or you could do what Ryan suggested and check for indexes where you have True.
